# How to do a jQuery trigger on checkbox or radio so that it is exactly the same as a user clicking it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that is using can.js so it is harder to reproduce on jsfiddle.net, but the end result is this:

If I click on the checkbox (or it can be a radio button as well), then another `input` text box will update the changes that was due to my click.  (for example, the text box will now say "Blue").

However, if I do it programmatically using jQuery right inside of Firebug's console or Chrome's developer tool console:

```
$("#some-form input:eq(3)").trigger("click");
```

or

```
 $("#some-form input:eq(3)").click();
```

then the checkbox on the webpage will get checked in fact, but the `input` text box value will not update to "Blue" like before.

So to emulate even more closely a user clicking on the checkbox using code, I tried:

```
$("#some-form input:eq(3)").trigger("focus");
$("#some-form input:eq(3)").trigger("mousedown");
$("#some-form input:eq(3)").trigger("mouseup");
$("#some-form input:eq(3)").trigger("click");
$("#some-form input:eq(3)").trigger("change");
```

but all of the above together still will not emulate a user manually clicking on the checkbox.

Although it can be complicated that the can.js code was using either can.compute() or can.Observe() to update that `input` text box, BUT the key is, if a user manually clicking on the radio or the checkbox can work, why not programmatically.  In other words, what can be done programmatically that is almost identical to a real physical click?  Is there some events that I missed possibly?

(more details: this is tried on the most recent Firefox and Chrome, so it should not be a browser issue.  Also, I tried even  first focus and then trigger a keydown event with a SPACE character and it still won't have the effect.  What is more strange is that, if I do trigger the click **twice**, then the `input` text box actually shows the update to "Blue", so why twice?).

Answer (score -1):

The answer is, it is due to a jQuery bug:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3827

I can reproduce it by using:

```
// strange behavior:
$("#some-form input:eq(3)").click();
```

and if replaced by a native `click`:

```
document.getElementById("some-form").getElementsByTagName("input")[3].click();
```

then it works perfectly on Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

So the fix seems like came out with jQuery 1.9, which was on Jan 15, 2013.

There is more info in: [In jQuery, why after a trigger of click on an unchecked checkbox, the event handler reports it is not checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778985/in-jquery-why-after-a-trigger-of-click-on-an-unchecked-checkbox-the-event-hand)